# Gatsby redirect to home page instead of displaying 404 page

Tags: gatsby

Is it possible to somehow redirect the user to the home page (`/`) instead of displaying the 404 page?

Comment: For sure you can do it on the client at `404.js` and just change `window.location`, but even better would be to do it server side, e.g. with [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#custom-404).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gatsby creates 404 page from `src/pages/404.jsx` (or `404.js` if you are not using `jsx` extension). So, creating a component which redirects to the home page there should do trick, something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function NotFound() {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.location = '/';
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 63):

Other answers here will eventually fail because the `window` object is not defined at build time.
Use this instead. The `useEffect` hook is equivalent to `componentDidMount`.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { navigate } from "@reach/router"

export default () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigate('/your-redirect/');
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```

Comment: This is the only option that worked for me without error or warning.

Comment: I must also add, that redirecting on the HTTP level is usually better for UX and SEO. If you're hosting on Netlify, you can configure your redirects as shown [here](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-redirects-file). I advise you to keep the method in my answer as a fallback, for when you're in development and also in case you had to abruptly switch hosting providers.

Answer (score 8):

You can do the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from '@reach/router'

const NotFoundPage = () => <Redirect to="/" />

export default NotFoundPage
```

Comment: not working, because of the reason below: the `window` object is not defined on build time

Answer (score 8):

You can also do it with `navigate()` (formerly `navigateTo()`, thanks @pgarciacamou)

```
import React from 'react'
import { navigate } from 'gatsby'

const NotFoundPage = () => {
  return navigate('/')
}

export default NotFoundPage
```

Comment: Just fyi, as per GatsbyJS docs: "_**Note**: `navigate` was previously named `navigateTo`. `navigateTo` is deprecated in Gatsby v2 and will be removed in the next major release._". See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/

Comment: Also, navigate should be called from useEffect, otherwise Gatsby runs it during buildtime